# Need values from most recent rows for multiple records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following:

```
UserID    SomeValue     DateUpdated
------------------------------------
1         263           2019-09-07
2         abc           2019-09-10
1         123           2019-09-10
2         234           2019-09-11
1         573           2019-09-20
```

I need a query that will return distinct UserID, the most recent DateUpdated value, and the corresponding SomeValue for the most recent record.

I've tried an outer join on a sub-query of the same table.  Didn't produce expected results.

```
SELECT B.UserID, B.SomeValue, B.DateUpdated 
FROM thetable B
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(SELECT UserID, MAX(DateUpdated) AS DateUpdated 
 FROM thetable GROUP BY UserID) x
ON x.UserID = B.UserID AND x.DateUpdated = B.DateUpdated
```

But it returns a lot more than expected.

From the above data example, I would expect to get:

```
UserID    SomeValue     DateUpdated
------------------------------------
2         234           2019-09-11
1         573           2019-09-20
```

In my production table, I have 3,670,108 records.  The Outer Join returned 3,669,774, but there are only 1,182,525 distinct UserIDs in the table.  So I would expect the results to be 1,182,525 rows.

Any assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: The join is going to produce multiple results when you have more than one row with the same date (per user). That probably accounts for the unexpected rows. The fact that the two numbers are very close is then probably a coincidence.

Comment: Lets start with a sanity check and see how close we come to 1,182,525    Select Count(*) From (SELECT UserID, MAX(DateUpdated) AS DateUpdated  FROM thetable GROUP BY UserID)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [`row_number()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
select userid, somevalue, dateupdated
from (
  select *, row_number() over (partition by userid order by dateupdated desc) rn
  from thetable
) t
where rn = 1
```

Or with NOT EXISTS:

```
select t.* from thetable t
where not exists (
  select 1 from thetable
  where userid = t.userid and dateupdated > t.dateupdated 
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ae04f660033ba8c6d895523b0a00a988).
Results:

```
> userid | somevalue | dateupdated        
> -----: | :-------- | :----------
>      1 | 573       | 2019-09-20 
>      2 | 234       | 2019-09-11
```

Comment: The second query, with NOT EXISTS, gave me a dead on answer.  Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: It means your solution gave me the count and dataset I was looking for.  Much appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

A correlated subquery often has very good performance for this problem:

```
SELECT B.*
FROM thetable B
WHERE B.DateUpdated = (SELECT MAX(B2.DateUpdated)
                       FROM thetable B2
                       WHERE B2.UserID = B.UserID 
                      );
```

For performance, you want an index on `thetable(UserId, DateUpdated)`.